# How can I get a custom delimiter used for an S3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, prefix

As it is mentioned on [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-prefixes.html) page, one can specify a custom delimiter for organizing their keys in a S3 bucket.

I am writing some code where I want to concatenate directory and file names together, and I would like to use that delimiter, but I want to acquire it programatically. Is it possible to acquire that information from S3 through python?

I checked [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket) documentation page for the S3 bucket object and could not find something myself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delimiter is not a setting on the bucket. It's just a parameter you can pass to certain S3 API calls.

Comment: The first link I share mentions: "To do this, first pick a delimiter for your bucket, such as slash (/), that doesn't occur in any of your anticipated key names. You can use another character as a delimiter. There is nothing unique about the slash (/) character, but it is a very common prefix delimiter." 

Do you have some explanation for that?

Comment: You would pick a delimiter to use in all your interactions with that bucket, but there is no setting on the bucket itself that forces you to always use that delimiter. You downvoted me and then asked me to prove a negative. I can't link you to any documentation that says "this setting for buckets does not exist". All I can do is point out that is seems to be impossible to find that S3 bucket setting...

Comment: I did not downvote you and I found the downvote super ridiculous without explanation since it only made me more confused as to why your answer is not good. So the answer I guess is that you pick the delimiter during your interactions with the bucket and there is no setting on a bucket level. Thank you.